# Why can't Jupiter be seen over Thanksgiving break?

Tags: astronomy, planets

As of these past few days, Jupiter can be seen in the sky, correct?  Around Thanksgiving, why can't it be seen?

Answer (score 4):

I noticed Jupiter was quite brilliant near the Moon Friday night. From my location, central North America, Jupiter will be easily seen most of the evening for the next few months at least.

What makes you think it won't be seen? Where do you live?

There would have to be a lot of light pollution for it to not be visible. The only other reason why it wouldn't be visible (besides clouds) is that it might be beneath the horizon during the night when viewed from your location on Earth.

You can use [this U.S. Naval Observatory (USNO) website](http://aa.usno.navy.mil/data/docs/mrst.php) to calculate the rise and set times for Jupiter.

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure where you're getting your information on "Around Thanksgiving, why can't it be seen?"  Jupiter will be easily visible around Thanksgiving pretty much from all locations, and it's bright enough that light pollution (even in New York City) should not drown it out.  In fact, on Nov. 24 (Thanksgiving this year), the moon will be almost new, preventing even less problems for viewing Jupiter.

On November 24, Jupiter rises at about 3:00 PM and sets around 4:30 AM (used a latitude of 40° to make that calculation, no daylight savings).  So it'll be in the sky all night, bright and easily viewed.

Answer (score 3):

Install Stellarium, input your location in the program's settings, then go to the Date/Time tab on the left and set the date to Thanksgiving at 10pm. Voila, Jupiter is high and bright in the sky.

http://stellarium.org/